# R: Call Matlab function and pass arguments

Tags: r, matlab

Is it possible to call a Matlab script in R so that the functions it contains can be called within the R script with arguments afterwards?

For Python there is the function `source_python()` (https://rdrr.io/cran/reticulate/man/source_python.html) from the library `reticulate`. It allows to make all public (non-module) objects within the main Python module available within the specified R environment. So I can call functions I wrote in Python within an R-script like every other function, passing arguments and get return values.

I am looking for this functionality for Matlab. I found the library `matlabr` which contains the function `run_matlab_script()` so I can get the output from Matlab but it does not provide passing variables from R to Matlab and run functions considering them.